# Is having high cardinality more important than even access when trying to avoid hot partitioning?

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-design, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I'm designing a database schema where there are only 2 partition keys, however, both partitions will be accessed equally - every time I access partition A, I will also access partition B. Will this design suffer from hot partitioning?

From my understanding, hot partitioning occurs because of uneven accesses to the partitions resulting in some partitions being "hot". So I'm thinking cardinality does not matter as long as the accesses are even. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about uneven.

Put very simply, each partition key may get put with it a certain amount of underlying capacity. The more partition keys, the easier for the system to add capacity as you need it. Does your database need a lot of capacity? If so, you may want to design with a different (more diverse) key strategy. If your needs are basic, don't overthink it and just get going.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm not worried about uneven because even access is built in to the use case - it is certain that partition key A will be queried/updated the same number of times as partition key B. Is it still possible to have hot partitions (I know I only have 2 partition keys which is very less but both are used equally)? The total number of items will be a few million max.

Comment: What’s your WCU allocation? Below 2,000? Proceed. Above 2,000? More questions must be asked. Also RCU, but there it’s 6,000.